# cursor.moveToFirst seems to be skipped

Tags: java, android, sql, database, cursor

I'm new to Java and just tried to make a database. I managed to make a DB and all but when I want to read the values it seems to get an error.

This is my code for my settings activity (which asks for setting values and add them in the DB on a specific ID)

```
public class Settings extends Activity{

    Button Save;
    static Switch SwitchCalculations;
    public static String bool;
    public static List<Integer> list_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static List<String> list_idname = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<String> list_kind = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<String> list_value = new ArrayList<String>();
    static Integer[] arr_id;
    static String[] arr_idname;
    static String[] arr_kind;
    static String[] arr_value;
    public static final String TAG = "Settings";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        SwitchCalculations = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchCalcOnOff);

        readData();

        Save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                        writeData();
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "Data has been saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        readData();

                    Save.setText("Opgeslagen");
            }
        });
    }
    public void writeData() {
            int id = 1;
            String idname = "switchCalcOnOff";
            String kind = "switch";
            boolean val = SwitchCalculations.isChecked();
            String value = new Boolean(val).toString();

            dbHelper_Settings dbh = new dbHelper_Settings(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(dbh.C_ID, id);
            cv.put(dbh.C_IDNAME, idname);
            cv.put(dbh.C_KIND, kind);
            cv.put(dbh.C_VALUE, value);

            if (dbh.C_ID.isEmpty() == true) {
                db.insert(dbh.TABLE, null, cv);
                Log.d(TAG, "Insert: Data has been saved.");
            } else if (dbh.C_ID.isEmpty() == false) {
                db.update(dbh.TABLE, cv, "n_id='1'", null);
                Log.d(TAG, "Update: Data has been saved.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "gefaald");
            }
            db.close();
    }
    public void readData() {
        dbHelper_Settings dbh = new dbHelper_Settings(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        List<String> list_value = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] arr_value;
        list_value.clear();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + dbh.C_VALUE + " FROM " + dbh.TABLE + ";", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list_value.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){

            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();
        arr_value = new String[list_value.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < list_value.size(); i++){
            arr_value[i] = list_value.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my dbHelper activity see below:

```
package com.amd.nutrixilium;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class dbHelper_Settings extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String TAG="dbHelper_Settings";

    public static final String DB_NAME = "settings.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 10;
    public final String TABLE = "settings";
    public final String C_ID = "n_id";  // Special for id
    public final String C_IDNAME = "n_idname";
    public final String C_KIND = "n_kind";
    public final String C_VALUE = "n_value";
    Context context;

    public dbHelper_Settings(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    // oncreate wordt maar 1malig uitgevoerd per user voor aanmaken van database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = String.format("create table %s (%s int primary key, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", TABLE, C_ID, C_IDNAME, C_KIND, C_VALUE);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: " + sql);

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE); // wist een oudere database versie
        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrate dropped table " + TABLE);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

And the weird thing is I don't get any error messages here.
But I used `Log.d(TAG, text)` to check where the script is being skipped and that is at `cursor.moveToFirst()`.

So can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here, contrary to what you seem to expect, you actually check that a text constant is not empty:

```
if (dbh.C_ID.isEmpty() == true) {
```

It isn't : it always contains "n_id"

I think your intent was to find a record with that id and, depending on the result, either insert or update.

You should do just that: attempt a select via the helper, then insert or update as in the code above.

Edit:

Add to your helper something like this:

```
public boolean someRowsExist(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select EXISTS ( select 1 from " + TABLE + " )", new String[] {});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    boolean exists = (cursor.getInt(0) == 1);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
```

And use it to check if you have any rows in the DB:

```
if (dbh.someRowsExist(db)) {  // instead of (dbh.C_ID.isEmpty() == true) {
```

Comment: How should i resolve this? How can i check if db row exists or not? can i use something simple like, db.C_ID.contains("1")?

Comment: As you are new to this, it is important to start the right way.  And it is by making sure you really understand **each** line of the code.  Just trying to put together some fragments never do the magic.  When you do know, you get the power of asking the right questions.  For example, googling for "android sqlite check if record exsists" will give you just a few links. But you can only ask those questions when you do understand what's going on. Please see my edit above; hope it helps.

Comment: Its almost a perfect code which you provided me.
In the someRowsExists after the cursor is set you should do cursor.moveToFirst();

Comment: A lot stuff posted is a sort of pseudocode - like mine above :).  That's why it is important to review everything - exactly what you did, thank you, edited the above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having trouble debugging your query. Android provides a handy method [DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursorToString%28android.database.Cursor%29) that formats the entire Cursor into a String. You can then output the dump to LogCat and see if any rows were actually skipped.